# Excel: Is it possible to have a running two column list on one page and have it transfer to a secondary tab?

Tags: excel

I have a database tab which holds all my information for each item in my inventory. This is always changing as I add new inventory. I want to take certain information in that tab (columns A & B) and use it in a separate tab called stock inventory in columns A & B. When it transfers I would like a blank cells in columns C,D,E, and F. I did try VLOOKUP however, because column A on the database tab is repeated, when the information was transferred to the stock inventory tab it duplicated information instead of actual information. For example Column A may say "Scale" column B may say "abalone, there may be a second entry with the same information in column A but different information in column B. When it transfers to the stock inventory tab anytime it recognizes "scale" in the column A it would say Abalone. This is not what I want. I want to bring over actual information for column B even if column A is the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of the repeated value in the VLOOKUP you could create helper column on the left of the first vlookup matrix column, with the formula =ROW()&A2, and use this value as key to be searched with vllokup instead of the value in A1: there will be no duplicates, as the value will be the concatenation of the row number and the name of the article.